# How to find a proportion between two ratios

Tags: relations, correlation, derivation-of-formulae

I'm trying to calculate a max camera height based on camera size.
With a camera size of $540$, the max height is roughly $707$, and with a camera size of $215$, the max height is roughly $1032$. I can't figure out how to use those relationships to get a formula that I can input the camera size and get out a max camera height.

Comment: If it’s a linear relationship then use $h=ms+c$ where $m$ is the slope of the line and $c$ is the intercept on the $h$ axis. You have two points on this line so you should be able to work this out. where $h$ is the height and $s$ is the camera size.